# div dropdown, goes up when you click inside the div?

Tags: jquery, html, dropdownbox

I have the following script to drop down a div.
What is right is that when I click outside the div or choose another div to go down already dripped down div is going up.

But when I click on anything in the div so it should not go up?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#favorite_holder').click(function(e) {
        $('#favorite_container').slideToggle("fast");
        $('#account_container').slideUp("fast");
        $('#cart_container').slideUp("fast");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('#account_holder').click(function(e) {
        $('#account_container').slideToggle("fast");
        $('#favorite_container').slideUp("fast");
        $('#cart_container').slideUp("fast");
        e.stopPropagation();
    }); 

    $('#cart_holder').click(function(e) {
        $('#cart_container').slideToggle("fast");
        $('#favorite_container').slideUp("fast");
        $('#account_container').slideUp("fast");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function(){
        $('#favorite_container, #account_container, #cart_container').slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="favorite_holder">
    <span class="price">click here</span>
</div>
<div id="favorite_container" style="display: none;">
    content here...
</div>
<div id="account_holder">
    <span class="price">click here</span>
</div>
<div id="account_container" style="display: none;">
    content here two ...
</div>
<div id="cart_holder">
    <span class="price">click here</span>
</div>
<div id="cart_container" style="display: none;">
    <form>
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
    </form>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/GVYEd/11)

Comment: @laras: you dont want to slideup when you click outside any div ?

Comment: refactored http://jsfiddle.net/GVYEd/15/

Comment: Yes, I want it to go up when clicking outside a div or another div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
$('#favorite_container, #account_container, #cart_container').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GVYEd/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Easy method with your html and javascript:

Html:

```
<div id="favorite_holder" class="parent">
    <span class="price">click here</span>

<div id="favorite_container"  class="child" style="display: none;">
    content here...
</div>
</div>

<div id="account_holder" class="parent">
    <span class="price">click here</span>

<div id="account_container" class="child" style="display: none;">
    content here two ...
</div>
</div>


<div id="cart_holder" class="parent">
    <span class="price">click here</span>

<div id="cart_container" class="child" style="display: none;">
    <form>
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /> <br\>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').click(function() {
        $('.child').slideUp("fast");            
        $(this).find("div").slideDown("fast");           
    });


    $('.child').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });   
});
```